# MSSQL and SQLSRV let php check what to use

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sqlsrv

I want to connect to my Ms sql server. The webserver is Linux but my Localhost is Windows. Right now I comment out the one I dont need but, is there a way PHP can check if it needs SQLSRV for windows or MSSQL for Linux?

```
<!--

linux

-->
<?php
// $server = 'server';
//
// $link = mssql_connect($server, 'user', 'password');
//
// //select database
//
// mssql_select_db('DB');
//  if (!$link) {
//      die("Connection could not be established.<br>");
//  }
?>

<!--

Windows

-->
<?php
$serverName = "server"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"DB", "UID"=>"user", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if(!$conn ) {
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br>";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

Comment: Personally I'd suggest you look at using vagrant and running a linux devenv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') {
  //use windows
} else {
  //use mysql
}
```